# How to solve this third degree polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

Can you explain me how to solve this kind of polynomial?

$$x^3 - 3x^2 = 320$$

Comment: Are you acquainted with the rational roots test?

Comment: Well - you might "spot" the fact that 320 factors as $5\times8^2$, and notice the factorisation $x^2(x-3)$ of the left-hand side, which then show that $x=8$ works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the rational roots test. If you have $a_n x^n + \ldots + a_0 = 0$, with $a_n \ne 0$ and $a_0 \ne 0$, and no common factor among all the coefficients, if $x = p / q$ is a root with $\gcd(p, q)$ ($p/q$ in lowest terms), you can write:
$$
a_n p^n + a_{n - 1} p^{n - 1} q + \ldots + a_1 p q^{n - 1} + a_0 q^n = 0
$$
Now $q$ divides all terms except possibly for $a_n p^n$, so $q$ divides $a_n$, and similarly $p$ divides $a_0$. If (as in this cases) $a_n = 1$, the only possible rational roots are integers.

You can cut down on the checks to do by using [Descartes' rule of signs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs), if there are $m$ changes of signs in the sequence of coefficients, there are $m$ or $m - 2$ or $m - 4$ or... positive roots.

Also note that [cubic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function) and [quartic (or biquadradic)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function) have general solutions (but they are rather horrible). Perhaps the simplest solution is to ask your tame computer algebra system for the roots.

Comment: And fortunately, with Wolfram Alpha these days you don't even need to buy/install your own computer algebra system: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x^3-3x^2-320

Comment: @user7530, [maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net) is open source and runs most anywhere

Answer (score 1):

A little trying shows that $x=8$ is a root. And the polynomial now factors as $x^3-3x^2-320=(x-8)(x^2+5x+40)$. The other roots are $$x_{12}=\frac{-5±3i\sqrt{15}}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

If all the roots are integers then each of them must divide the constant term. This is because over the complex numbers a third order polynomial factors as $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$ where $a,b,c$ are the roots. So the constant term, in this case $320 = abc$. So you might try plugging in integers which divide $320$ until one of them is a solution. Say you plug in $a$ and it solves the polynomial. Then the polynomial $x-a$ must divide $x^3 -3x^2 -320$. After performing division you will have $p(x)(x-a) = 0$ where $p(x)$ is a second order polynomial which can be solved using the quadratic formula to find the other two roots $b$ and $c$.